# create structured clone of Proxy

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I have a class that returns a Proxy from the constructor. When I try to store instances of this class in IndexedDB, or send the object using `window.postMessage()`, I receive an error stating that the object could not be cloned. It appears that the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) cannot handle Proxy objects.

The following code demonstrates the error:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      set(target, prop, val, receiver) {
        console.log(`"${prop}" was set to "${val}"`);
        return Reflect.set(target, prop, val, receiver);
      }
    });
  }
}

const obj = new MyClass;

try {
  window.postMessage(obj,'*');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);

}
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this problem? I see two potential solutions, but I don't know how I might implement them:

1. Do not return a Proxy from the constructor, but maintain the Proxy functionality within the class declaration somehow.
2. Alter the Proxy instance so that it works with the structured clone algorithm.

**EDIT:** The following, simpler code also demonstrates the structured clone error:

```js
const p = new Proxy({}, {});
window.postMessage(p, '*');
```

Comment: Having just learnt that this is a thing. All I can do is laugh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the original, non-proxied object in a class property, and use it when you want to pass it to `postMessage`. You can change the constructor to have an optional parameter which will be passed to the proxy instead of `this`. This way you can recreate the object by passing it to the constructor.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(original = this) {
    this.original = original;
    return new Proxy(original, {
      set(target, prop, val, receiver) {
        console.log(`"${prop}" was set to "${val}"`);
        return Reflect.set(target, prop, val, receiver);
      }
    });
  }
  export() {
    return this.original;
  }
  static import(original) {
    return new MyClass(original);
  }
}

const obj = new MyClass;

obj.test = 1;
console.log(MyClass.import(obj.export()).test);
MyClass.import(obj.export()).test = 2;

try {
  window.postMessage(obj.export(), '*');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```