# How to make a structuredClone of a Proxy object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, browser

I'm using Vue3 where a lot of the objects are Proxy objects for reactivity. I want to create a deep copy of one of the proxy objects and recently discovered structuredClone.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

When I run the following code, I get an error performing a structuredClone on proxyObj:

```
const obj = {
    name: "Steve",
    age: 50
}
const handler = {}
const proxyObj = new Proxy(obj, {})

console.log(proxyObj)

const objCopy = structuredClone(obj)

console.log(objCopy)

const proxyObjCopy = structuredClone(proxyObj)
console.log(objCopy)
```

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': # could not be cloned.

Is there a way I can clone the proxy object? Is there a way I can dereference it first, copy it, and not lose the reactivity? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To be clear, you are not responsible for the creation of the Proxy and have no access to the target object, right? Otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118839/create-structured-clone-of-proxy could have helped.

Comment: Correct, the proxy creation is done behind the scenes as far as I can tell

Comment: And would a simple `structuredClone({...proxyObj})` get you all the expected key-value pairs or is your the object more complex than the example you gave?

Comment: That does work and is nicer than the Object.assign implementation I found. The only issue is that it strips the proxy. I'll have to check for my use case if I need the reactivity after I do this assignment.

Comment: Proxy is not supported, end of the story https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#supported_types . Any way, it's unlikely a reactive object would work as intended this way, I'd expect it to have internal state. You need to stick to composition API to compose objects and maintain reactivity

Comment: Can you elaborate on stick to composition API? The way I'm handling it is using @kaiido 's solution. When I return from the copy with the stripped proxy, I map the properties of the result to the property in state that has the proxy. It's a bit hacky, but looks like that'll have to do since Proxy copies aren't supported. Thank you

Comment: This is how this can be done with Vue proxies, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72632173/unable-to-use-structuredclone-on-value-of-ref-variable/72633173 . This doesn't apply to the code in the question because it uses raw proxies which cannot use the same approach.

Comment: @Kaiido I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Spread syntax requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function`

Comment: `structuredClone` returns a clone of the *structure*. It does loose reactivity by definition.

Answer (score 9):

If you're just talking about Vue3 and no nested proxies you could just use [`toRaw`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw) directly:

```
import { reactive, toRaw } from 'vue';

const obj = reactive({ foo: 'bar' });

const objCopy = structuredClone(toRaw(obj)):
```

---

Having come across a few cases where I had objects with nested proxies or arrays of proxies etc, I had to go the extra mile and create my own `toRawDeep`.

Since it uses [`toRaw`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw) it should work with proxies created by `reactive()`, `readonly()`, `shallowReactive()` or `shallowReadonly()`.

```
import { toRaw } from 'vue';

export function toRawDeep<T>(observed: T): T {
    const val = toRaw(observed);

    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
        return val.map(toRawDeep) as T;
    }

    if (val === null) return null as T;

    if (typeof val === 'object') {
        const entries = Object.entries(val).map(([key, val]) => [key, toRawDeep(val)]);

        return Object.fromEntries(entries);
    }

    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to to convert Proxy object to standard object. Check this answer :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77144575/5372505

In the case you presented :

```js
const obj = {
    name: "John",
    age: 50,
    children: [{
        name: 'Sam'
    }]
};

const proxyObj = new Proxy(obj, {});
const objOneLevelCopy = {...proxyObj};
// const objCopy = structuredClone(proxyObj) // throw Error
const objStructuredCopy = structuredClone({...proxyObj});

obj.name = 'Amanda' // change a value
obj.children[0].name = 'Mike'; // change a sub value

console.log({obj}) // { name: "Amanda", age: 50, children: [{name: 'Mike'}] }
console.log({proxyObj}) // { name: "Amanda", age: 50, children: [{name: 'Mike'}] }
console.log({objOneLevelCopy}) // { name: "John", age: 50, children: [{name: 'Mike'}] }
console.log({objStructuredCopy}); // { name: "John", age: 50, children: [{name: 'Sam'}] }
```

Answer (score -1):

Following your example you can create your own function using `Object.create` and `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`

```
function cloneProxy(obj) {
    //creates a new object that inherits from the prototype of the original object
    const clone = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
    const properties = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
    
    for (prop in properties) {
        if (properties[prop].hasOwnProperty("value")) {
            clone[prop] = properties[prop].value;
        } else {
            clone[prop] = properties[prop];
        }
    }
    
    return clone;
}

const obj = {
    name: "Steve",
    age: 50
}
const handler = {}
const proxyObj = new Proxy(obj, {})
console.log(proxyObj) //{ name: 'Steve', age: 50 }

const objCopy = structuredClone(obj)
console.log(objCopy) //{ name: 'Steve', age: 50 }

const proxyObjCopy = cloneProxy(proxyObj)
console.log(proxyObjCopy) // { name: 'Steve', age: 50 }
```

For more info about these functions:

`Object.create` --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors