# Unable to use structuredClone() on value of ref variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to make use of the [structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) function inside my Vue app. I want to use this to create a deep clone ( instead of using workarounds like stringify and parse or external libraries ). Inside my setup function the following code is fine

```js
const a = {
  foo: {
    bar: "+"
  }
};
const b = structuredClone(a);

console.log(b);
```

But it is not possible for me to use it on values of ref variables. This example code

```
import { ref } from "vue";
const a = ref({ foo: { bar: "+" } });
const b = structuredClone(a.value);
```

throws the error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': # could not be cloned.

The same goes for items from ref arrays

```
import { ref } from "vue";
const a = ref([{ foo: { bar: "+" } }]);
for (const b of a.value) {
  const c = structuredClone(b);
}
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: See the section [Things that don't work with `structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#things_that_dont_work_with_structured_clone)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The error means that `structuredClone` was executed on `Proxy` instance, which [cannot be cloned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#supported_types). In order to allow this, it should be used on raw object that a proxy wraps:

```
const b = structuredClone(toRaw(a.value));
```

Notice that `toRaw` is used on `a.value` because both `a` and `a.value` are reactive objects, and `toRaw` works shallowly and needs to be applied to the innermost object.

Since `ref` and `reactive` allow to compose reactive objects, `toRaw` still may not work for them due to how it works:

```
ref({ foo: { bar: barRef } })
```

This would require to recursively use `toRaw` on reactive objects before using `structuredClone`. At this point this doesn't make it easier than cloning the objects manually, unless more exotic objects like `Set`, `Map`, etc are in use.