# I can't deep clone an object and I'm not sure why? Maybe a promise related issue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm requesting json data in a vue component. I'm able to get this data and store it in an object 'this.employees'.

Next, I want to make a deep clone of this object as 'this.cloneEmployees'. I will be allowing the user to filter the data in 'this.employees', so I will use the clone 'this.employees' for when I need to reset the filters and restore the full set of data.

However, the code at the end of this post results in this error:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: DataCloneError: The object can not be cloned.
```

I've tried other methods like `obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))` which resulted in the same error.

I don't really know what I'm doing, but I think it might be the case that this fails because  'this.employees' does not actually exist when `this.cloneEmployees = structuredClone(this.employees)` runs. So, I thought it would be fine to just wrap it in `.then()` and everything would be fine, but this doesn't work. I've looked around and I can't find a solution. What is wrong?

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      employees: [],
      cloneEmployees: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/employees")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(
        (response) =>
          (this.employees = response.map((e) => ({
            ...e,
            subjects: e.subjects.split(",")
          }))))
  
        this.cloneEmployees = structuredClone(this.employees)
    
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72632173/unable-to-use-structuredclone-on-value-of-ref-variable

Comment: It's a mistake to access the result outside .then. You can't structuredClone a proxy, which 
reactive values are in vue 3 (something that the question doesn't mention). "which resulted in the same error" - this is unlikely as JSON... methods are legit workarounds for the problem and cannot cause the same error. In your case, you can just use a temp var to clone instead of cloning this.employees

Comment: Estus, thanks for the reply. I understand a bit better now. You're right about the error—I misremembered—it doesn't generate an error, but simply doesn't work how I need it to. I was able to solve this by changing a line to:          `(this.employees = this.cloneEmployees = response.map((e) => ({` This seems like a good, simple solution and seems work fine.

Comment: It possibly didn't work at least because of mishandled .then. The problem is this isn't a clone as the name implies but a reference. you'd change employees by mutating cloneEmployees, and the opposite way