# How can I reliably convert a proxy to a standard object?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I'm working with events in JavaScript, and often the event is a proxy object. When debugging I can usually use this to get a copy of the object.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail)));
```

Sometimes (today, a few times), this outputs a proxy object again, but if I don't parse it, I get the raw string with the information I need:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail));
```

Why is `JSON.parse` turning a string into a proxy object? How can I get a copy of the embedded object *every* time?

Comment: This proxy? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: You're not affecting the `event` object at all (proxy or not) when you `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail))` you're only manipulating the `detail` property, and even that as a clone of the property stored in the `event`.

Comment: No. Unless you (or a library you're using) have overwritten `JSON.parse`, it does **not** return a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can do a shallow clone of a Proxy.

```js
let proxy = new Proxy({ foo: 1, bar: 2 }, {});
let cloned = { ... proxy };

console.log(cloned);
```

In your case, you could try `{ ... event.detail }` to get a shallow clone of the object.