Vue.js different functionality when calling util in script vs template (and accounting for template unpacking)
toRawDeep clones nested proxy object (calling toRaw at each level to clone the original proxy object).
// this works as expected (updates to prop.rowData in parent do not change what is rendered in the ag-grid-vue component)
import {toRawDeep} from './utils'
const props = defineProps({
    rowData: {type: Array}
})

const r = toRawDeep(props.rowData)
</script>

<template>
  <ag-grid-vue :rowData="r" />
</template>


// updates to prop.rowData in the parent are reflected in the ag-grid-vue component. Not what I would expect.
<script setup>
import {toRawDeep} from './utils'
const props = defineProps({
    rowData: {type: Array}
})
</script>

<template>
  <ag-grid-vue :rowData="toRawDeep(rowData)" />
</template>

Anyone know why these 2 behave differently?  My understanding is that props.rowData should be unpacked to rowData in the template, therefore these should do the same thing.

You may want to use toRawDeep inside a computed in case rowData is expected to be updated, this would be the correct approach in general because it provides caching behaviour. What's toRawDeep btw? This one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77022014/3731501

Yes, toRawDeep is from that answer.  rowData may get updated in the parent, but I don't want any link between the prop rowData passed in, and the rowData maintained in this component.  Don't think I need "caching" for anything, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

In your snippet 2 toRawDeep is executed on each render, including those that aren't related to ag-grid-vue, and toRawDeep can be potentially computationally expensive. This is exactly the case to wrap it with a computed, so it would be executed only when props.rowData is updated. If your intention is to not update child's rowData when it's updated in a parent then snippet 1 is correct and 2 is not.

Got it, and yes the code was updated to use snippet 1 (but wanted to confirm snippet 1 had no need to use computed).

That is probably because <ag-grid-vue :rowData="toRawDeep(rowData)" /> will rerun toRawDeep(rowData) every time an update is made to props.rowData. Whereas const r = toRawDeep(props.rowData) is only run once when the component is first loaded.

That would make perfect sense...didn't realize toRawDeep would be called on every change.

Yep! That is because everything in the template tag needs to be re-interpolated when you make changes to variables. Though, for performance reasons, it gets a lot more complicated than that (and is why you need specify what variables are reactive). You can learn more about it at Reactivity Fundamentals and Reactivity in Depth.
